# NSUndoManager Disaster

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsundomanager

I'm an enthusiastic 16-year-old programmer, and right now I'm working on an app, a simple one that just has a button that adds 1 to an integer and displays it in a label, & I'd like to add an undo button. From I have researched NSUndoManager is supposed to help. The thing about it is I can't get it to work! This question might seem obvious, but I've learnt all I know from youtube, and therefore don't know many things. 
This is my code:

```
@implementation ViewController

NSUndoManager *undoManager;

-(IBAction)add1:(id)sender{

    Count = Count + 1;

    Counter.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", Count];

    [undoManager prepareWithInvocationTarget:self];

    [undoManager registerUndoWithTarget:self selector:@selector(add1:) object:Counter.text];
    [undoManager setActionName:NSLocalizedString(@"actions.update", @"Update Score")];
}

-(IBAction)Undo:(id)sender{

    [undoManager undo];
    Counter.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", Count];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    Count = 0;

    undoManager =[[NSUndoManager alloc]init];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
@end
```

When you answer, please try not to say very technical words, or if you do define them because, as I said before, I don't know many things and I might not understand what you say, and I seriously want to learn this. A sample code of my app but with the NSUndoManager programmed correctly would be great so I can compare it and find out what my mistakes are.

Thanks!

Comment: Explain what actually happens when you undo, and how you trigger the undo

Comment: Try placing the three lines of code for your `undoManager` from your `add1` method into your `viewDidLoad` lifecycle method, after you alloc/init the `undoManager`. Does that help?

Comment: How do I do that? Perhaps a sample code would help.

Comment: Did you solve your problem? need more information?

Comment: I really didn't :/ I want to program it so that when I hit the undo button instead of running an method the I programmed that makes essentially undoes, it just remembers what it did last time and undo it :P What I have been told in the answers is that I need to program a method that does what I would like to happen when I call undo, but that would be the same as just declaring an IBAction Method that does undoes, and the NSUndoManager would be useless, you kind of see what I need?

Answer (score 0):

You need a method which is the opposite of your `-add1:` method. Then, you need to set that as the selector for the undo action:

```
- (IBAction) add1:(id)sender
{
    Count = Count + 1;
    Counter.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", Count];

    [undoManager registerUndoWithTarget:self selector:@selector(subtract1:) object:sender];
    [undoManager setActionName:NSLocalizedString(@"Increment Score", @"Name for undo action")];
}

- (IBAction) subtract1:(id)sender
{
    Count = Count - 1;
    Counter.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", Count];

    [undoManager registerUndoWithTarget:self selector:@selector(add1:) object:sender];
    [undoManager setActionName:NSLocalizedString(@"Decrement Score", @"Name for undo action")];
}
```

So, the way that `-add1:` is undone is by calling `-subtract1:` and the way that `-subtract1:` is undone is by calling `-add1:`. Also, since `-subtract1:` registers an undo action, that means that you get redo functionality. (An undo action registered in the process of undoing is understood to be the redo action if the user chooses to redo what they undid.)

Note: you don't use `-prepareWithInvocationTarget:` when you use `-registerUndoWithTarget:...`. You use one or the other.

Also, your `-Undo:` method should not need to set `Counter.text` because that should be done automatically by the undo action.

Comment: so then if I do a big app that gets statistics of a baseball game, for example, I would have to write the whole code but backwards? Or is there a way of managing a whole program so that the changes are registered and then the program just resets the whole thing back to what it was before at the latest change happened?

Comment: I don't think of it as writing anything backwards. In any typical program, you're going to provide both operations anyway. You could also write your code in a more general fashion, like having a method which adds a given value to the count, not necessarily 1. Then you could invoke it with 1 for the increment operation and it would register an undo operation that invokes itself except with the value negated. (That is, your simplified example of an `-add1:` method is too simple and thus unrealistic. More realistic code would not require such an awkward method for the undo action.)